# Glue database connection update username aws cli/boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, aws-glue

Trying to update Glue database JDBC connection username and keep failing. choices are CLI or boto3.
CLI docs are so limited.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/update-connection.html

```
  update-connection
[--catalog-id <value>]
--name <value>
--connection-input <value>
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

Can someone guide, how to pass username to update here. Also similar in boto3. Throwing exception of invalid parameter.

```
response = client.update_connection(
        Name='test-db',
        ConnectionInput={
            'Name': 'test-db',

            'ConnectionType': 'JDBC' ,
            'ConnectionProperties': {
                'Username': username
            }
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'ConnectionProperties': {
            'USER_NAME': 'your_user_name',
            'PASSWORD' : 'your_user_password'
        }
```

Caution: Above is not tested. Its based on Glue Boto3 documentation from [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html).

Answer (score 0):

So it supposed to be like this.

```
  'USERNAME': username,
  'PASSWORD': password
            },
   'PhysicalConnectionRequirements': PhysicalConnectionRequirements
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add all of the details for the update_connection:

```
    glue_client = boto3.client('glue')
    glue_client.update_connection(
        Name='Redshift-Rosko',
        ConnectionInput={
            'Name': 'Redshift-Rosko',
            'ConnectionType': 'JDBC',
            'ConnectionProperties': {
                "USERNAME": username,
                "PASSWORD": password,
                "JDBC_ENFORCE_SSL": "true",
                "JDBC_CONNECTION_URL": "jdbc:redshift://...:5439/rosko_db",
                "KAFKA_SSL_ENABLED": "false"
            },
            'PhysicalConnectionRequirements': {
                'SubnetId': 'subnet-......',
                'SecurityGroupIdList': [
                    'sg-......',
                    'sg-......',
                ],
                "AvailabilityZone": "eu-central-1a"
            }
        }
        )
```